# print page source in python playwright

Tags: python, python-3.x, webautomation, playwright, playwright-python

I have PHP script, and Im calling python function with this code with URL parameter:

```
import json
import sys
import urllib.parse
link = urllib.parse.unquote(sys.argv[1])
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36')
    page = context.new_page()
    cookie_file = open('./cookies.json')
    cookies = json.load(cookie_file)
    print(cookies)
    context.add_cookies(cookies)
    page.goto(link)
    try:
        page.wait_for_timeout(10000)
        print(page.innerHTML("*"))
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()      
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in playwright script.")
        page.close()
        context.close()
        browser.close()
```

However, when I want to print the page source after I visit the page, I receive

```
Error in playwright script.
```

because code that I tried doesnt works:

```
print(page.innerHTML("*"))
```

any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the full HTML content of the page you can use `page.content()`.

Comment: I tried but i recive this  <bound method Page.content of <Page url='www.url.com'>>

Comment: @liol see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47210219/2373249

Comment: use await page.content() , instead of just using the synchronous one ,